# How to get current playing time of MPMoviePlayerViewController after seeking?

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

How to get current playing time of MPMoviePlayerViewController after seeking ? Originally I am using a NSTimer to count the time played, but after scrubbing / seeking, the time recorded does not count the amount of time seeked.

Any way to know current time of video or amount of time scrubbed ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The currentPlaybackTime property in the MPMediaPlayback protocol gives you that info.

Comment: Hi, how do you get this protocol to work? It's properties are not listed in the original Frameworkfile MPMoviePlayerController.h, therefore I can't use it :(. Perhaps you know something (please see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3937931/get-mpmediaplayback-properties-for-an-mpmovieplayercontroller-object )

Comment: Micko, you're referring to MPMoviePlayerController, which probably means you're working with the iOS 3.1 framework, while Shivan was referring to MPMoviePlayerViewController, available in iOS 4.0 framework. I'm not aware of a comparable method in iOS 3.1.

Comment: U can implement the MPMediaPlayBack Protocol where u can get the currentPlayBack property...